# What could be the reason for CannotGetJdbcConnectionException?

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Does anybody have an idea where to look for the cause of the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-240] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:0; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
```

What I find really strange is that it says that no connections are available while none are busy.

Everywhere that I look, the same error occurs but the number of busy connections is at least greater than 0.

I don't know whether this matters, but Tomcat version is 8.5.20.

Any idea are welcome!

Comment: Does your code close connections when it is done with them (because that is what returns them to the connection pool)? Also note that although none are busy, also none are idle. This could indicate that there is an exception deeper in the stacktrace that indicates it can't connect to the database. Please post the full exception stacktrace and your connection pool configuration.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkRotteveel! Seems that the connection is closed properly and unfortunately deeper stacktrace is not printed in the server logs. I will try find out whether it is indeed the problem of the db being disconnected. Thanks for the ideas!